# remove / hide added backslashes from MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have about a thousand entries that all contain backslashes throughout the entry. Is there an easy way, or a script that can delete a specific character from every entry?

Comment: which is server side language php ?

Comment: tried stripslashes($yourvalue) where you displaying vales from database ?

Comment: are you actually wanting to remove the slashes from the database, or just change how they're displayed?

Comment: @Chris : it's working ? ok now with stipslashes ?

Comment: @Teez it is, just reading in all the entries and updating with the string after stripslashes()

Comment: @Chris :not getting what you want to say. can we discuss over chat ?

Comment: @Teez that's alright. simply put, it works and the database looks the way it needs to

Comment: @Chris : ok then I am putting it in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace should do your job.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
UPDATE table_name SET col=REPLACE(col, '\\', '')
```

This should work. It will update the column replacing `\` with the empty string. I just do not remember if you have to escape the `\`, using `\\` or just `\`. Check it before running the query, using `SELECT col, REPLACE(col,'\\','') FROM table_name` and see if the result is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Might be backslashes are added in database to escape quotes due to `magic_quotes` on . You should not remove them from there.

You should use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)($yourvalue) PHP function where are you displaying vales from database on your page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on @Enrico's solution (and yes, I know this is a two-year-old question, but it's high in Google results), but I can confirm that his query works. Additionally, you can use a `where` clause to limit to only those results that actually contain a backslash (useful for checking before executing).

Check:

```
SELECT col, REPLACE(col,'\\','') FROM table_name WHERE col LIKE '%\%' ESCAPE '|'
```

Execute:

```
UPDATE table_name SET col=REPLACE(col,'\\','') WHERE col LIKE '%\%' ESCAPE '|';
```

The `escape` clause is used to set the escape character in the `like` clause (but not the `REPLACE()` function). Since we're working with backslashes, we change the escape character to ensure we get what we want.

Note also that you may need to `set SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0` first, depending on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you may add :

```
public function init()  
{       
       $this->view->setEscape('stripslashes');  
}
```

This will escape slashes while display.

If you want to remove slashes while insertion to DB you may use:

```
stripslashes($your_value)
```

If you just want to remove the slashes from current data you ma do :

```
UPDATE table_name SET col=REPLACE(col, '\\', '')
```